# Apache redirect only specific urls

Tags: apache, proxy, http-redirect

I'm setting up a testing environment with one proxy and two backend servers.

I want to redirect like this:

```
example.com/app1/ -> apache_1
example.com/app2/ -> apache_2
example.com and all the rest to apache_1
```

I already have the first two redirects working with this config:

```
<Location /app1/>
    ProxyPass http://apache_1/
    ProxyPassReverse http://apache_1/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Location /app2/>
    ProxyPass http://apache_2/
    ProxyPassReverse http://apache_2/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Now I want to add something like:

```
<Location 'everything else'>
    ProxyPass http://apache_1/
    ProxyPassReverse http://apache_1/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

If I use Location / the apache redirects everything to apache_1 and doesn't find shows a 404 on localhost/app1/ and /app2/

Is this possible with apache?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you were a little more clear but if you have no other content on example.com, then the best solution I could think of is an `ErrorDocument 404 /file`.

In the file, you can use an HTML `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=your-url" />
```

The in the `content` attribute, the 0 means the page will refresh after 0 seconds, redirecting to the url.

Or you could include a php `header`:

```
header("Location: url");
```